# How to pass Duplex Stream in formdata?

Tags: node.js, stream, duplex

Image saved in s3 is downloaded as a stream and it is piped to duplex stream. The stream which is coming from s3 should be sent in `formdata` to another remote URL which when done with fs.createReadStream works but not with the duplex stream.

**code**

```
const download = (url, duplex) => {
  axios
    .request({
      url,
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "stream",
    })
    .then((response) => {
      response.data.pipe(duplex);
    });
};

const mainFunction = () => {
  const duplex = new PassThrough();
  download("some_url", duplex);

  // duplex.pipe(writeStream) works and writes to file
  // send formdata
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append("file", duplex); // should work? as it is duplex

  // this does not work
  await axios.post(url, form, {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    ...form.getHeaders(),
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

So here is what was missing and finally found it. Some destination expects file mimeType when you're sending stream in `formdata`.

**Solution**

```
const download = (url, duplex) => {
  axios
    .request({
      url,
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "stream",
    })
    .then((response) => {
      response.data.pipe(duplex);
    });
};

const mainFunction = () => {
  const duplex = new PassThrough();
  download("some_url", duplex);

  const form = new FormData();
  // heres what was missing 
  form.append("file", duplex, {
    filename: 'hola.jpg',
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  }); // Voila! It works.

  await axios.post(url, form, {
    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data",
    ...form.getHeaders(),
  });
};
```